# Correctly measure L7805ACT regulator output

Tags: voltage-regulator, multimeter

I am trying to measure the output of a L7805ACT voltage regulator ([datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-115/DSAP00566.pdf)) with a multimeter, without any additional parts (no caps, etc, just the regulator). I'm using a regulated wall adapter power supply with settable output (5-12VDC). The adapter's connector can be inversed so + becomes -, but I paid attention to connect it the right way.

The multimeter I'm using is an [EXTECH EX330](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/ex330/portable-digital-multimeters/extech/#).

Here's the regulator's pin layout:

[image: L7805ACT pins]

Steps:

- set multimeter to VDC setting
- attach COM probe to regulator's GND (middle pin)
- attach red probe to output pin (3rd)
- connect wall adapter to input pins (1 and 2)
- switch the wall adapter on

Diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5s8lr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the first regulator I tried, the multimeter displays the **input** voltage and the regulator quickly heats. No voltage drop whatsoever.

At first I thought 12V input is too much, 7V have to be dissipated as heat and that the overheating is normal, so I set the input to 7.5V, but the results were the same.

Changed the wall adapter, same thing. Measured the adapter's output power with the same multimeter, 7.5V exactly as set.

Tried with another regulator, 7.5V input, and now the measured output voltage starts from about 7V and rapidly drops to 0 (didn't really waited to get to 0, don't want to see the regulator burning).

Although the multimeter shouldn't be the problem, as even without connecting it the regulator still heats, I thought to change the multimeter batteries. Low battery indicator was showing on the multimeter, although the batteries were only half discharged. I changed them anyway. Same result.

So what am I doing wrong? Does the regulator need a load on the output, like a resistor? This might sound stupid, but does the multimeter draw too much current from the regulator?

I know this is a basic task, but it got me a little frustrated after possibly destroying 2 brand new regulators.

Comment: Schematic? It needs to be wired up according to the data sheet. Don't forget the capacitors.

Comment: While schematics are always good in this case maybe you could also post a clear photo of the setup? Some of the pin numbers you're using above don't match the numbering in the datasheet, so it's not clear if you're using those or counting left to right.

Comment: Left to right, 1 In, 2 Gnd, 3 Out, with the regulator's inscriptions facing up.

Comment: Ok, added a schematic

Comment: What about the capacitors? Regulators can oscillate without them.

Comment: @talereader I'd misread the part about burning as that was currently happening (getting warm). It probably just needs the caps as Leon suggests to maintain regulation properly, especially when connected to a high impedance meter input.

Comment: I thought the caps are optional, for stability. There are tutorials for measuring a regulator directly with a multimeter, no caps. Maybe this reg in particular is more sensitive than a LM7805. So, a 0.33uF on input and a 0.1uF on output?

Comment: @talereader, it does differ between parts and that datasheet doesn't really state whether they're needed or not, many also say to use the input cap when you're some distance from the power source which you probably are. Personally I've never not used them so I don't know how likely the symptoms you're seeing are.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the meter set to measure voltage, and not current?  If you connect an ameter bewtween the 7805 output and ground, the meter will appear as an alomst zero ohm load, and olverload the regulator - that would account for the regulator overheating.

Comment: Turns out both regulators were busted. I don't remember where I got them from, they looked unused, but who knows. I tried with the same model but bought at a different time, maybe from another supplier, and works as expected. Removed the caps, still working with the bare regulator. I suspected that something as simple as this had to have a simple explanation. How should I close the question?

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes I'm sure the dial was set correctly, and it was V(olts) being displayed. I learned my lesson when I blew the multimeter's fuse 1 month after I bought it.

Comment: How can you claim that you're testing a part "outside any circuit", and then give a circuit diagram for the test arrangement?

Comment: @Kaz Well, what I meant was "without any additional parts" because I guess I couldn't really test without putting it in a circuit, but I understand your point that the formulation isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected that something as simple as this had to have a simple (yet improbable) explanation and it did.

Turns out both regulators were busted. I don't remember where I got them from, they looked unused, but who knows. I tried with the same model but bought at a different time, maybe from another supplier, and works as expected.

The testing setup was correct and filter capacitors aren't really needed (at least for testing purposes), but I'll use them anyway as recommended. Thank you all for your input.